# how to pass embed code in javascript

Tags: javascript, smarty

```
<a href="" onClick="return select_item(<embed src=\"player.swf\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" quality=\"high\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" FlashVars=\"id=&flv=1257568908_.flv\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"450\" height=\"371\"></embed>')>
```

The above returns an "unterminated string literal" error.

How to solve this issue. This function is inside smarty template.

Thanks for every answer

Answer (score 3):

I've also run into situations with Smarty where it tries to evaluate Javascript as Smarty template code.

In that case, you need to surround the Javascript with [`{literal}{/literal}`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.literal.php) tags.

---

However, in your case, I think you're missing a single-quote at the beginning of `select_item(` and a double-quote at the end of the `onClick` event:

```
<a href="" onClick="return select_item('<embed src=\"player.swf\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" quality=\"high\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" FlashVars=\"id=&flv=1257568908_.flv\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"450\" height=\"371\"></embed>')">
```

I'm not 100% sure if you really need to backslash-escape the double-quotes that are part of the `<embed` HTML.

For that amount of markup, I find it easier to read and debug if you **don't** do it inline as part of the `onClick` event.  I use PrototypeJS so I'd handle it like this

```
<a href="#" id="doSelectItem">Click Here</a>


//Handle the click event of the above a tag
Event.observe($('doSelectItem'), 'click', function(event) {
  var markup = '<embed src=\"player.swf\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" quality=\"high\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" FlashVars=\"id=&flv=1257568908_.flv\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"450\" height=\"371\"></embed>';

  if( select_item(markup) ) {
    //select_item returns true, so let the click event continue
  }else {
    //select_item returned false so cancel the click event.
    Event.stop(event);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get

```
unterminated string literal
```

then it basically means that you have started a String, but never ended it. E.g.

```
var foo = "bar;
```

Solution is obvious: terminate it:

```
var foo = "bar";
```

Another common cause is using the **same** quotes inside the String as with which the String is wrapped:

```
var foo = "my mom said "go out!" to me";
```

You need to escape such quotes then:

```
var foo = "my mom said \"go out!\" to me";
```

In your specific case you have `"` inside the HTML string which is on its turn wrapped inside another `"`s of the `onclick` attribute. So:

```
<a href="" onClick="return select_item('<embed src="player.swf" ...
```

needs to be replaced by

```
<a href="" onClick="return select_item('<embed src=\"player.swf\" ...
```

Comment: but the mozilla error console indicates the error in first character.
That is "<". what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ') is missing at the end of your onClick event, hence the JavaScript error. You also need to escape the double quotes. The line should look like:

```
<a href="" onClick="return select_item('<embed src=\"player.swf\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" quality=\"high\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" FlashVars=\"id=&flv=1257568908_.flv\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"450\" height=\"371\">');">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much confusion about escaping quotes in javascript and HTML, especially when they are mixed like this.

Straight off the bat, **try to avoid this situation in the first place**. HTML is for markup, Javascript is for behaviours. That said...

In Javascript, you escape quotes with a backslash. This is so that when javascript interprets the string it knows where it ends.

```
var name = 'O\'Reilly';
```

In HTML, you use ampersands and a character code.

```
O&quot;Reilly
```

Just remember that when you are writing code in your HTML, **it's not being interpreted by javascript, it's being interpreted by the HTML parser**. To a HTML parser, a backslash is just a regular character.

```
<a onclick="foo(&quot;bar&quot;);">
```

Now you see why I'd recommend avoiding the situation in the first place. Here's the alternative:

```
<a id="myLink">

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = function() {
        foo('bar');
    };
</script>
```